# What is the best way to upload a large number of files to azure file storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-files, azure-node-sdk

I want the file storage specifically not the blob storage (I think). This is code for my azure function and I just have a bunch of stuff in my `node_modules` folder.

What I would like to do is upload a zip of the entire app and then just upload that and have azure unpack it at a given folder. Is this possible?

Right now I'm essentially iterating over all of my files and calling:

```
var fileStream = new stream.Readable();
fileStream.push(myFileBuffer);
fileStream.push(null);

fileService.createFileFromStream('taskshare', 'taskdirectory', 'taskfile', fileStream, myFileBuffer.length, function(error, result, response) {
  if (!error) {
    // file uploaded
  }
});
```

And this works its just too slow. So I'm wondering if there is a faster way to upload a bunch of files for use in apps.

Comment: What happens if you try uploading the files concurrently?

Comment: I altered it to do this, but its still way too slow for my expectations. It went from something like 30 minutes to 5 minutes. But it seems like there is a `kudu` api for sending and unpacking zip files. I'm still trying to figure it out and if I manage to I will post results here.

Answer (score 0):

> And this works its just too slow. So I'm wondering if there is a faster way to upload a bunch of files for use in apps.

If Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library is acceptable, please have a try to use it. The [Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement) designed for **high-performance** uploading, downloading and copying Azure Storage Blob and File. This library is based on the core data movement framework that powers [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy).

We also could get the demo code from the github [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement).

```
string storageConnectionString = "myStorageConnectionString";
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
string sourcePath = "path\\to\\test.txt";
CloudBlockBlob destBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

// Setup the number of the concurrent operations
TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
// Setup the transfer context and track the upoload progress
SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext();
context.ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>((progress) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
});
// Upload a local blob
var task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(
    sourcePath, destBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None);
task.Wait();
```

Comment: I'm using nodejs so I can't use this library directly, I'm trying to look into the code and see what api's its using though. I'm also using File not Blob.